# Libvirt Cannot Stop Reboot Force Shutdown or Destroy Guest

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

The subject pretty much says it all.   I am running libvirt (KVM?) on Ubuntu and I have two guests (both ubuntu server) that I cannot access or control.

That is, if I view them with virsh or virt-manager, their status is "running".   I cannot connect to the graphical console.   If I send the keys ctrl-alt-del nothing happens.  If I try to "shut down" I get the error "error shutting down domain.  Timed out during operation.  cannot acquire state change lock".

I really cannot just delete these guests and start over.   How can I recover them?

Comment: would you please restart the libvirtd daemon process via command `service libvirtd restart`? you can dump the domain xml via command `virsh dumpxml <guest-name>` then you can see the graphic device. usually you can use any VNC client connect to it to see the desktop. Finally, you can destroy the running VMs and restart the VMs. just use command `virsh destroy <guest-name>` and `virsh start <buest-name>`, your guest OS will just experience one restart.

Answer (score 6):

There could be qemu-kvm process(es) running for the guests. kill them manually (kill -9) and then start it from virt-manager/virsh.